# Index based list, returning a element at nth index

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-requests

```py
class IBList:

    maxlen = 100                        # pre-allocated size of list

    def __init__(self):
        self.r = 0                      # current size of list
        self.list = [0] * self.maxlen
```

How do I return a element at index `r` and return string "error" if `r < 0`  or `r > size - 1` and replace with an element `e` at index `r` and return the element that is being replaced?

Comment: Can you give an example of input and expected values?

Answer (score 0):

You can user **len()** to get the length of a list. Also, you can replace values from list using `mylist[index] = new_value`.

```
def my_func(lst, r, e):
    if r < 0 or r > len(lst)-1:
        return 'error'
    else:
        lst[r] = e
        return lst[r]

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
r = 2
e = 22
print(my_func(lst, r, e))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, splitting your problem into two separate functions `get_elem` and `elem_replace`:

```
class IBList:
    maxlen = 100                        # pre-allocated size of list

    def __init__(self):
        self.r = 0                      # current size of list
        self.list = [0] * self.maxlen

    def get_elem(self,r):
        if r >= 0 and r <= len(self.list)-1:
            return self.list[r]
        else:
            return 'error'

    def elem_replace(self,r,e):
        elem = self.get_elem(r)
        if not elem == 'error':
            self.list[r] = e
            return elem
        else:
            return None # Handle this case any way you want.
```

Comment: thanks but i have no learn try-except method yet in my syallbus, any way to get element at index r and return error in one code. Then replace the element e at index r and return the element that is being replace and return the string "error" in another code if r<0 or r>size -1. both in separate codes?

Comment: @Peter sorry for the delayed response, I have updated my answer if you would like to take a look.